# gitlab-ci.yml ignoring docker image in private runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Well, I created a private runner in my Digital Ocean VPS. This private runner is using *shell executor*, and this is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  VERSION_NAME: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_CONCURRENT_ID}

before_script:
  - docker info

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
  - delivery

test_project:
  tags: 
    - safepark
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1
  script:
    - dotnet test

build_image:
  tags: 
    - safepark
  only:
    - master
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -f WebApi/Dockerfile -t myuser/myimage
    - docker tag -t myuser/myimage myuser/myimage:${VERSION_NAME}

push_image:
  tags: 
    - safepark
  only:
    - master
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker push myuser/myimage
    - docker push myuser/myimage:${VERSION_NAME}
```

But in "test" stage the image is never pulled and I got "dotnet command not found". But If I change to a shared runner everything works fine. Seems like "image" is ignored by gitlab runner. How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to use a Gitlab Runner with docker, you have to [use the `docker` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#register-docker-runner) instead of a `shell` executor.

You can only run commands locally on the machine that runs the executor when [using the `shell` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html).

I assume that it's working on the shared runner as it might have a docker executor.

Comment: But if I use docker executor can I use commands in host Machine too? Some stages of my CI will be executed in docker and others not, like "docker build" command

Comment: You can assign different runners to different jobs using tags. A runner will only pick up jobs if he has the tags of the job. You can then e.g. run the tests within a docker runner and afterwards execute the `docker build` command in a different runner with `shell` executor.

Comment: Can I use same machine with multiple runners type ? I have a machine in digital ocean and I would like to use this machine to shell and docker runner.

Comment: Yes, you can register multiple runners on the same machine using `gitlab-runner register`